# How to test selectOption

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a controller that queries users to be selected in a vf page. I want to write a test class to test the code. The problem is I can't seem to populate the selection in my test so that it goes through the code.

The controller grabs the options:

```
public void fetchusers() {
if (selectedAttendeeType=='Search Account Team'){
        Id accountId = account.Id;
        for (User npdUser: [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE IsActive=true AND Id IN (SELECT User__c FROM NPD_Account_Team__c WHERE Account__c = :accountId OR Parent_Account__c = :accountId) ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 1000]){
            possibleNPDAttendees.add(new SelectOption(npdUser.Id, npdUser.name));
        }
    }
```

The vf page the user selects the value:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(account.RecordType.DeveloperName!='Practice_Account', 'true', 'false')}">
  <input type="radio" id="accountTeamList" name="Attendee" value="Search Account Team" checked="true" onclick="setSelectedSearch(this.value);"/>
  <b><label for="accountTeamList">Search Account Team</label></b><br/>
  <input type="radio" id="allNPDList" name="Attendee" value="Search All NPD" onclick="setSelectedSearch(this.value);"/>
  <b><label for="allNPDList">Search All NPD</label></b>
 ...
<c:SL_SelectBoxes id="attendeeSelection" leftOption="{!possibleNPDAttendees}"
       rightOption="{!NPDAttendees}"
       size="14"
       width="350px"
       height="100px"/>
```

In my test class tha I am rebuilding from an existing test the developer just called the methods and didn't actually test anything.

```
....
callReport.selectedAttendeeType = 'Search Account Team';
callReport.fetchusers();
```

I have some users created in the test class, so I thought of doing the following to grab my user created in test and assign it to the select option so it would mimic being selected by the user.

```
callReport.npdattendees.add(user1.id, user1.LastName);
```

However, I get this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List].add(Id, String)

If I just add the Id I get:

> Incompatible element type Id for collection of System.SelectOption

How can one test adding a selection value?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Yes, and no I added the line which solved one chunk but didn't cover a different chunk which used the same logic, then I went to try something on the vf page and I got a totally different error than what I was looking at so now I'm just getting ready to punch walls..

Comment: Not advisable for your health or programming ability to punch walls.

Comment: Well, if this resolved your errors, perhaps it should be considered close and you can demonstrate in a new post what you're trying to cover? This question isn't really phrased as asking about coverage so much as asking why you can't add `SelectOption`(s) to the `List`.

Comment: right, I was stuck trying to get the value into the select option so technically closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you receive that error is because you omitted the constructor.

Instead of:

```
callReport.npdattendees.add(user1.id, user1.LastName);
```

do:

```
callReport.npdattendees.add(new SelectOption(user1.id, user1.LastName));
```